Cloud Scheduler failing to schedule Cloud Run Job
I am trying to schedule a Cloud Run Job using the Console according to the documentation. I have set up my job and it works perfectly. After defining the schedule, I clicked on FORCE RUN on Cloud Scheduler but it fails.
The Error is: "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished",
"status":"NOT_FOUND",
"targetType":"HTTP"
I have tried using a different service account with no Cloud Run Invoke permission, and I got "status":"PERMISSION_DENIED". So that's not the problem.
I have checked the location and it's fine, .../locations/europe-west3...

Does this answer your question? Scheduled Cloud build trigger throws 404 NOT_FOUND error
